# Element Triple tap

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tap

How can i perform triple tap in Xamarin on a specific element?
I tried with for loop performing a single tap 3 times, but it looks like it is slow cause it's not working.

```
public void AppLaunches()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <= 3;i++)
            {
                app.Tap(x => x.Css(".app-logo"));
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `TapGestureRecognizer` in code or XAML and set the number of taps required to trigger the associated event or command:

XAML using event handler:

```
<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" >
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="3" Tapped="Handle_Tapped"/>
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

The Event handler:

```
    void Handle_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Triple tap on {sender}");
    }
```

Re: [Adding a Tap Gesture Gesture Recognizer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/)

**Note**: Triple taps work fine on iOS, but Android does **not** support triple tabs as a standard feature (it does support double taps).

Re: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=32874

If you need triple tabs on Android, you can capture each tap individually (NumberOfTapsRequired="1"). If it is the first tap, set a local variable to 1 and start a background timer that expires in X milliseconds, if the next tab occurs before the timer has expired, restart the timer and 1 to your local variable, repeat until you get three taps. If the timer expires have it reset the local variable back to 0.

Comment: Thanks, this way too complicated dor triple tap action.